# Acceder a los campos de un Json en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, json

Se que es una pregunta que se ha formulado muchas veces pero a mi no me funciona lo que he leido hasta ahora.

Tengo un botón que hace la función de login. Al pinchar, manda los datos que hay en los TextViews a la url y recibe un Json. La respuesta si el login es correcto es algo asi:

```
{
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ1YnJpc2VjdXJpdHkiLCJzdWIiOjEsImlhdCI6MTU2MDc1NjM5MiwiZXhwIjoxNTYwNzU5OTkyfQ.YGLa9w2xwxVm07-T1O3F5XrWBjc2y_hCB_lT3G1QQAI",
"idCliente": 1,
"nombre": "Miguel Ángel"
```

}

Mientras que si es erroneo es:

```
{
"error": "Email or password is wrong."
```

}

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
JSONObject map = new JSONObject();
    try {
        map.put("correo", Email);
        map.put("password", Password);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest strRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, map, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            System.out.println("Mensaje: " + response);
            JSONObject jsonChildNode;
            try {
                jsonChildNode = response.getJSONObject("0");
                String Token = jsonChildNode.getString("token");
                System.out.println("Mensaje: " + Token);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Mensaje Error");
            //Log.e("JsonObjectRequestRespo", "::" + error.toString());
        }
    }
    );
    requestQueue.add(strRequest);
```

Como veís, tendo dos System.out para ver lo que se recibe. El primero funcion bien para el caso de exito (aun no probe el error) y recibo el json (esta es la salida por la consola:

```
*2019-06-17 09:25:52.946 I/System.out: Mensaje: {"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ1YnJpc2VjdXJpdHkiLCJzdWIiOjEsImlhdCI6MTU2MDc1NjM1MSwiZXhwIjoxNTYwNzU5OTUxfQ.E4zlg5achP702TvSVPE6Pr2LKGe7aJn5ElToQpAcJdk","idCliente":1,"nombre":"Miguel Ángel"}
*
```

Pero el segundo no hace nada. De hecho si inicializo el string token a null me muestra eso mismo, null.

He probado ciento de soluciones pero no doy con la tecla. ¿Me podeis ayudar con lo que hago mal? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías crear primero el objeto Json y luego coger el token de la forma que lo haces es como si cogieras el objeto de un JsonArray y no es el caso.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
String tokenString = jObject.getString("token");
```

**EDITO

En tu caso si realmente la respuesta te llega como un JSONObject con hacer la segunda linea ya te debería bastar

```
String tokenString = response.getString("token");
```

Comment: En uno de los intentos use la opcion `JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);` pero me marcaba un error. De hecho, quitando todo el bloque try-catch que tenia el codigo anterior y poniendo tu solución me marca en rojo el response que hay en new JSONObject y el getString.  ¿Crees que el error puede venir de la declaracion new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()?

Comment: Has probando la segunda opción que te puse? String tokenString= response.getString("token"); sin todo el código extra que tiene por ahi tal cual llega la response

Comment: Ostras si. Con la segunda opción accede. Directamente con esa linea. Muchas gracias, de verdad.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Me ayudo bastante